# Taking derivative of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

When I was reading my lecture note examples, I came across some expression about a DE like this. Edit: $y$ is a function of $x$.
$$ y'=y-x-1$$
And for 
$$f=y-x-1\to f'= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} f $$
I have some experience with both multi-variable calculus and DE, but this second expression had me lost. What exactly happened there?

Comment: What does $f'$ mean here? $f'(x) = \frac{df}{dx}$?

Comment: It's part of, if not the reason I am lost I guess. So I asked here hoping someone can see what does $f'$ means. Now I am looking at previous notes trying to find similar context."ANd for" is the only 2 words between these two equations

Comment: Yes. It's fine, look: the derivative of a function $f(y(t),t)$ respect to $t$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$ times $dy/dx$ plus the explicit dependence on $x$. You have the first and the last. But notice that $f$ is actually $dy/dx=y'$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining first and second equation 
$$
y’ = y + x + 1 = f
$$
you get $f=y’=dy/dx$, otherwise it is the total differential of $f$ divided by $dx$.
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dx} +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx} =
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} f
$$

Comment: Right, this is it. total derivative. thank you.